# how to make a select to delete with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm still a bit new to jquery. I am trying to do this project for fun: http://jsbin.com/pevateli/2/

What I want is that when you enter something and add it to the list you will be able to select it and click on the top right image to delete.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $(".del").slideDown(100);
        var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
        $(".list").append("<div class='item'><input type='checkbox'/>" + toAdd + "</div>");
    });
});
$(document).on("click",".del",function(){
var rmv = $("input:checkbox:cheked").val();
    $(rmv).remove();
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>To Do</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="a style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="a script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h2>To Do</h2>
    <form name="checkListForm">
        <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
    </form>
    <img style="display:none;" class='del' src='del.png' align='right' width='20px'>    </img>
    <div id="button">Add!</div>
    <br/>
    <div class="list"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
h2 {
    font-family:arial;
}

form {
    display: inline-block;
}

#button{
    display: inline-block;
    height:20px;
    width:70px;
    background-color:#cc0000;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:2px;
}

.list {
    font-family:garamond;
    color:#cc0000;
}
```

Again, live copy: http://jsbin.com/pevateli/2/

Comment: Firstly, you need to put the delegated `.del` click handler within the `$(document).ready()` code block. Secondly, your code contains no checkboxes, so I'm not sure what value you're expecting to grab.

Comment: You've misspelt **checked** as **cheked**.

Comment: Always put all of the relevant code, markup, and style rules **in** the question, don't just link, not even to JSBin. I've done it for you this time. :-) Also, there's no need to force linebreaks in your text. Just type a paragraph, and if you need a line break, press Enter twice. Make use of the preview area underneath the text editor, and the toolbar above. (Don't get the wrong idea: You did great for a first question, and granted it's your fourth question but still pretty well. You'll get the hang of it.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run through checkboxes, see if they are checked and then delete their container:

```
$(document).on("click",".del",function(){
    $('.checkbox:checked').parents('.item').remove();
});
```

I added the class `checkbox` to your checkbox to use it as a selector instead of using the `input` element. It's a better practice not to make your JS logic dependent on the DOM elements themselves.

Here is a working [demo](http://jsbin.com/qegicuwa/2)

Comment: You don't have to add a class. The selector `div.item input[type=checkbox]` will do, as it will only get the checkboxes subordinate to the div .item.

Comment: No need to run through checkboxes, you can use the `:checked` right on the selector.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, it's not a good practice to tie selectors to specific HTML tags. That's why I believe using classes is better.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/pevateli/3/

You had some errors in your delete code like Ramy said. Also, he said you need to select the parent item. This updated code fixed that.

Also, I changed the event from `$(document).on('#button', 'click', function() {});` to an on submit function. `$(document).on('form', 'submit', function() {});` and changed your div to a button type submit. This way, you can either hit enter to add an item, or hit the button.

One more thing I added, is removing the input's value on submit, this way you don't have to delete your previous item before creating a new one.

And you know what would make this really fun? `localStorage();`

Answer (score 0):

`var rmv = $("input:checkbox:checked").val()` will retrieve the value of the input, which is not helpful.

You are looking for this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".del", function () {
    // To be more precise use $('.item input:checked') or even $('.list input:checked') or put a class name on the checkboxes.
    $('input:checkbox:checked').closest('.item').remove();
});
```

A contrived example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/scottux/72ZxC/